# Is there a web LDAP administration tool?

Tags: ldap

We are going to implement LDAP for centralized authentication in our organization. Which is the best simple LDAP management tool available? Extra points if it's Open Source, free, or otherwise permits on-prem hosting.

Answer (score 0):

## [FusionDirectory](https://github.com/fusiondirectory/fusiondirectory)

FusionDirectory is free under the GPLv2. It's also packaged by Debian, and available in the repository.